# VSCode - launching/debugging a native X11 application

Tags: visual-studio-code, x11

Within VSCode 1.52.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 I am attempting to launch and debug a native C++ app compiled with gcc 9.3.0.

As I am not remoting to another machine the Remote X11 extension is not apropos to what I am attempting to.

My launch.json file is boilerplate and it is as follows:

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/03_embree_triangle_geometry",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {"name":"DISPLAY", "value":"localhost:0"}
            ],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true }
        }
    ]
}
```

Per other threads I am explicitly setting the environment variable DISPLAY=localhost:0 but this has no effect. Even though I have selected 0 it really has no effect.

If anyone might provides with any pointers I'd appreciate.